# How to debug this Firestore/React expression?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand the meaning of '.doc' and/or 'doc' in Firestore, and am thus unable to get my documentReference...

```
const getIt = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const item = [];
    const docRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("polja")
      .doc("id", "==", match.params.id);
    //
    console.log(docRef);
    //
    docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
      setItem(doc.data());
      // //
      setLoading(false);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `.doc()` when you know the document ID and then the query goes as follows:

```
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("polja").doc("documentId");
```

But in case you are looking for documents with a specific field value, then you are looking for `.where()`

```
const docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("polja").where("id", "==", match.params.id);
```

This can match multiple documents where the value of that field matches the supplied value. So to control the number or results returned, use a [limit clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) or [paginate your query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors).

If you use `.doc()` function, then the variable `doc` in the response is a DocumentSnapshot. You can then use `doc.data()` to get its data.

On the other hand, if you use `.where()`, it'll return `FirebaseFirestore.QuerySnapshot<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData>` which contains all the documents matching the condition you had specified in the .where(). To access all the documents in that QuerySnapshot, you must access the docs property like this: `snapshot.docs`.
Now this will be an array of documents. You can use `snapshot.size` to see how many documents have matched your query.

Some practical examples to clarify:

```
//Collection in Firestore:
users -> {userID as documentId} -> user data in the document
```

```
//In this case you know the userID then you can should use the .doc()
const userDocRef = firebase.collection("users").doc("userId");
userDocRef.get().then((userData) => {
  console.log(userData.data())
  //^ this will contain data in side that document
})

//In this case, you want to find Firestore documents based on value of any field present in the document, lets say in this example if user's age is more than 15
const userDocsRef = firebase.collection("users").where("age", ">=", 15);
userDocsRef.get().then((usersData) => {
  console.log(usersData.docs)
  //^ this will log an array of documents which matched the condition of having the value of field age greater than or equal to 15
})
```

Comment: wait a minute - you were the one who told me that there is no use for '.where' when looking for a single document!

Comment: @ydrea but can you confirm that `match.params.id` is same as the document ID and there is only one document with that ID? If yes then please use `.doc(match.params.id)`. `.doc()` takes only 1 parameter that is the document ID. In you are question, you are passing 3 parameters.

Comment: @ydrea I've added more explanation, please use `.doc()` if you know the ID of that document.

Comment: @ydrea great! If your issue was resolved, you can accept the answer or please feel to ask further questions.